# Date conversion from csv to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm trying to import (through phpMyadmin import option) a csv file to mysql table. The CSV file has a column date with the format `mm/dd/yyyy` (10/21/2009) and the column in mysql table has the date format `yyyy-mm-dd`. I've tried to change formats in csv but after importing to mysql the date column shows `0000-00-00` or some other wrong dates. Which is the correct date format to be stored in the csv file so that it shows the correct date after importing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- Use a date column for the imported data (i.e. `varchar`)
- Add a column for the *new* date column (i.e. `Date`)
- Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert.
- Drop *old* date column (optional)

In your case:

```
UPDATE your_table SET new_date_col = STR_TO_DATE(old_date_col, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Adjust the original format to your needs.